# Refactoring duplicate code in C# net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an existing controller code in `.net core 2.0` as follow:

```
[Route("api/[controller")]
public class UserController: Controller
{
    DBConnect c = null;
    KeyCheck chk = null;

    public UserController(IOptions<SystemSettings> settings)
    {
        c = new DBConnect(settings);
        chk = new KeyCheck();
    }

    public CoreResponse EditUser(string key, [FromBody]User input) {

        // duplicate part start
        CoreResponse response = new CoreResponse();
        response.status = "fail";
        response.errors = new List<string>();

        if (!chk.isValidKey(c, key)) {
            response.errors.Add("Invalid Key")
        }
        // duplicate part end

        // query exection logic here
        response.status = "success"
        // query execution end

        return response;
    }
}
```

The part commented on duplicate part start and duplicate part end is repeated in every single place.
I would like to remove those part and become something like this. Is this possible and how could it be done. Or any other advice on refactoring these code?

```
[CheckKey]
public CoreResponse EditUser(string token, [FromBody]User input) {
    CoreResponse response = new CoreResponse();

    // query exection logic here
    response.status = "success"
    // query execution end

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Read up on Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) and Separation of Concerns (SoC)

Comment: Can't you just move the // duplicate part start and // duplicate part end to a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new instance of your controller is created for every HTTP request it serves, so you can safely move universal initialization logic into the constructor and move commonly used logic into a private method.

```
CoreResponse response;
public UserController(IOptions<SystemSettings> settings)
{
    c = new DBConnect(settings);
    response = new CoreResponse();
    response.status = "fail";
    response.errors = new List<string>();
}

// Could also return bool if you want the caller to take a different
// action if the validation fails.
private void ValidateKey(string key)
{
    chk = new KeyCheck();
    if (!chk.isValidKey(c, key)) {
        // Response already initialized in constructor
        response.errors.Add("Invalid Key")
    }
}

public CoreResponse EditUser(string key, [FromBody]User input) {
    ValidateKey(key);
}
```

Comment: This would be great if all access required a key, but unfortunately for my case not every request in a controller require a key to access. And how would i access the `key` params which is pass in from the request in  `if (!chk.isValidKey(c, key))` if it is initiated this way.

Comment: I missed that one of the parameters is passed into the individual method call. At a minimum, you can move everything that is common to every controller invocation into the constructor and move the rest into a common method as shown in the updated code (you would call the common method only from controllers that require a key).